# How does an op-amp create power?

Tags: operational-amplifier

If an op-amp or amplifier applies a gain to the input signal, does that mean it converts very low power signals into high power signals?

For example, a 741 op-amp has a gain of \$A_v = 10^5\$. That means it can convert a signal from a micro-volt range to a volt range.

Where does this power come from? How is this amplification possible? Doesn't it contradict basic laws of energy conservation?

Comment: Look up how an op amp actually works instead of just taking one over-arching statement about its operation and running to false conclusions with it.

Comment: The amplifiers are usually having additional power supply which is providing the power for the amplified signal.

Comment: The energy contained in the signal that comes out the op-amp actually comes from the power supply that powers the op-amp.

Comment: The opamp doesn't create power. The power supply supplies power. The opamp just modulates it.

Comment: https://www.explainthatstuff.com/amplifiers.html There is a section on this website (scrolling down a little) that says "Do amplifiers make energy?" Here it gives the answer to your question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the output power is almost always greater than the input power in op amps. Ideally, the input power is zero since the input resistances are infinite.

Here's a pinout for an 8-pin 741 op amp:

[image: 741 8-pin dual inline]

See the pins labeled +V and -V? Those are for power supply voltages. That's where the output power comes from. Conservation of energy is not violated.

Here's a non-inverting amplifier circuit that illustrates this. I included a bias current between +V and -V of 2.8 mA, which I took from a datasheet. As you can see, all power is accounted for. Surprisingly, only about 1/6 of the total battery power is delivered to the load! This is due to the large supply voltages and the low output voltage. You'll see this same low efficiency for the same reason in linear voltage regulators such as the 7805 and the 317.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLSNWg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Warning: CircuitLab does not simulate op amp supply voltage pins correctly.** If you try to simulate this circuit, you will get no current on +V and -V.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, opamps have a super high gain, providing high numbers of amplification close to infinity and beyond, [a few of them even go to eleven.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOO5S4vxi0o)

All that aside, you raised a valid point: that doesn't make too much sense under real world considerations.

Speaking of the real world, opamps aren't actually triangular boxes with a big number label on them.
Here's the [datasheet of the 741 opamp](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) I guess you were referring to in your question.

On page 4, you find a schematic diagram that replaces the nice simple "triangle with a big number" with a hell of a lot of transistors and a bunch of other stuff.
To me, this looks like a regular circuit, nothing more nothing less. More specifically, nothing really screams "I break the energy laws of physics" out to me.

But being a complicated circuit, it's still hard to see what's going on exactly.
That's why people came up with a substitute for this, which is that triangular symbol, with a very high gain.
It's just a model to simplify what's going on under the hood and it's a good one because it's really simple (compared to the circuit it describes) and allows you to do the calculations you want.

Like every model it has its limitations and requires common sense to be applied.

Comment: The energy contained in the signal that comes out the op-amp actually comes from the power supply that powers the op-amp.

Comment: I very nearly downvoted this one. The question asked, where does the power come from? And the answer is, "From the power supply."

Answer (score 1):

> Where does this power come from?

From the power supply pins. Op-amps don’t work when you don’t power them.